# Display table cell height 100% align image bottom

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using a `table` layout and attempting to set the height of the child of `table-cell` to be 100% of it's container. Why does this not happen and how do you resolve this?

I also tried setting the table-cell height to 100% without success.

I would like to align ONLY the images to the bottom of the container. How can I do that within a table display?

The amount of text in each table cell is dynamic

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u3gpf2n/1/

Comment: Your example doesn't contain a table.

Comment: He uses table in CSS.

Comment: Can we use flex? Because aligning one child to the top and another on the bottom is a piece of cake with flexboxes.

Comment: @woestijnrog as much as I love using flex-box, I need to support IE8 and IE9 :)

Comment: `div { min-height: 2.5em; }` but this is dirty :) ... but definitely cross-browser

Comment: @sodawillow I should mention, the content is dynamic. I don't know how many lines of text will be above the image and how big the table cell will be

Comment: I kinda guessed so ...

Comment: [here's a fiddle using bootstrap rows and columns](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/3u3gpf2n/5/)

Comment: @maioman I knew about this solution, but the problem with this is that now, the semantics of the block are gone. It's near impossible to make the blocks responsive as each Header+Image is not held within the same container. And responsiveness is another thing that I have to take care of unfortunately

Comment: Could you upload an image of what you want to achieve... So might there be a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like you're trying to create a 3-column, 2-row table, but only using single rows in order to keep your markup semantic. Without flexbox, distributing the image to the bottom will require some CSS trickery.

One example, which should fit your requirements of (1) cross-browser, including IE, compatibility (2) allow for arbitrary text in the box is:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-table;
}

li{
    position: relative;
    /* image width / (image height * column count) */
    padding-bottom: 11.764705882%;
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
    /* 100 / column count */
    width: 33.333%;
}

a{
    color: white;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li><a href><div class="header">Xiao Huang</div>
        <img src="http://3door.com/sites/default/files/styles/ablum_306_108/public/special/xiao_huang_ren_fu_ben_.jpg?itok=cPnwgTyV" /></a></li>
    <li><a href><div class="header">Xiao Huang</div>
        <img src="http://3door.com/sites/default/files/styles/ablum_306_108/public/special/xiao_huang_ren_fu_ben_.jpg?itok=cPnwgTyV" /></a></li>
    <li><a href><div class="header">Xiao Huang Xiao Huang Xiao Haung</div>
        <img src="http://3door.com/sites/default/files/styles/ablum_306_108/public/special/xiao_huang_ren_fu_ben_.jpg?itok=cPnwgTyV" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've added a relative position to the LI, and absolutely positioned the Image. To ensure things work correctly, I've given the cells a percentage-based width. I've also added padding to the bottom.

The one thing that this doesn't include is the cursor all the way down. If the user clicks between the image and text, the anchor will not be triggered.

To fix this, consider removing the UL/LI, and styling the anchor tags as table-cells and the wrapping DIV (or NAV, if you have a JS shim for HTML5 tags) as table.

Comment: That is the most hacky solution I have ever seen. Surely works, but that `image width / (image height * column count)` calculation.. ouch. Would suck if the images had different heights, eh?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using a table layout and attempting to set the height of the child
>   of `table-cell` to be 100% of it's container. Why does this not happen
>   and how do you resolve this?
>
> I also tried setting the `table-cell` height to 100% without success.

When using percentage heights in CSS you need to specify the height for all parent elements, up to and including `body` and the root element (`html`).

*From the spec:*

> [**CSS `height` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)
>
> **percentage**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.
>
> **auto**
>  The height depends on the values of other properties.

In other words, if you have not set an explicit height to the containing block (and the child is not absolutely positioned), then your child element with percentage height will have no frame of reference.

So the problem in your code boils down to this: You're missing a `height` on parents `ul`, `#container`, `body` and `html`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sedetcc6/

> I would like to align ONLY the images to the bottom of the container. How can I do that within a table display?

Although [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is well-suited for aligning elements in a table cell, in this particular case, because each image has a sibling that must not move, the `vertical-align` property is not useful.

But the images can be shifted with absolute positioning. Try this:

```
li{
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* establish nearest positioned ancestor for abs. positioning */
    width: 33.33%; /* new */    
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; /* new */
    bottom: 0; /* new */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sedetcc6/1/

NOTES:

- No changes to original mark-up
- For the record, this problem could be easily solved with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), but I understand it's not an option here due to a need for IE 8 & 9 browser support.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding the problem correctly, but my advice would be to make each anchor `display: table-cell` so they are forced to the same height, and then you can position all elements inside the anchor or even use background images instead of `<img />`

[JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/far8qtag/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to need is set a height for all your elements, e.g.

```
*{
    height: 50px;
}
```

You'll get your desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/asimplepeter/3u3gpf2n/10/

If the amount of text is going to be an issue, you can set `overflow: auto` for your `.header` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and display properties like 'table' and 'table-cell' things are correct.

1. But, the problem is that tables are rendered with auto height only. Because of this, eventhough you had set your container height, the table structure was not rendered with the proper height. So, along with container class, set height for 'ul' as well
2. regarding the position of image, you can set your margin-top to 100% or by calculating the size of the image and reducing that from the 500px container height will help you in positioning.

Hope this answers your all queries

**EDIT** As setting the margin is expand the table height, alternatively you can use css property like below

```
transform: translateY(Y);
transform-origin: left top;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i would think it is better mantain the height of cell according to the img because it's static and set header as absolute.

Something like that:

```
li{
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}



.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3gpf2n/12/